# Line art overlapping object

Tags: lineart

I have a simple scene. This is a screen capture of the viewport:

[image]

The tea cord is over the cup line art (it is right). When render, the line art become over the cord:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

[This is the file for review](https://pasteall.org/blend/70bba3af7acb42abb502dfb6103b68c6), if needed.

Thank you.

Comment: I *think* that's because of the line thickness, the endpoints are rounded and since the render is zoomed out a little compared to the preview, it appears they are connected when they are not. Try lowering the line art thickness

Comment: Good point. Unfortunately, with a minimun thickness of line art, results the same.

Comment: @Gorgious: That's the first time ever i knew something better than you here :D But you are still gorgious!!!!

Comment: @Chris hehe, nice catch ! Cheers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check "Z" in passes-data:

[image]

[image]